# Git - how to rename many folders?

Tags: git, bash, rename

I know the command `ls-files` generates a list of files you can use in a for loop to filter and rename all files, but what would be the command for just directories?  I'm trying to append the string "-dcmp" to all the directory names in a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no particular reason to do this with git, rather than with the usual bash tools. Specifically, I would just use `find`, myself, since it's the tool I'm used to using for doing similar things to many different files:

```
$ find . -name .git -prune -or -type d -exec git mv '{}'{,-dcmp} \;
```

Comment: The reason I want to do it with git is so that it records the changes as renames instead of file delete/add.  I'm assuming since this uses the mv command that git will recognize this as renames... I'm kind of tired so I'm having trouble deciphering this atm.

Comment: This just calls `git mv x x-dcmp` once for each directory `x` in your repository.

Comment: well it worked, it's magic to me right now, but it worked.  Thank you.

Comment: I added a thing to avoid going into the `.git` directory, which might have wreaked some havoc if you ran this in the root for your repo.

Comment: I ran it before you edited it and it didn't seem to affect anything in `.git` at all.

Comment: Yeah, I guess git probably knows better than to `git mv` stuff in there. Still, better safe than sorry. By the way, if this answer helped you, that's what upvotes are for.

Comment: Careful, this will also execute `mv . .-dcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the basic design of `git`, it does not manage directories.

Somewhat simplified, directories are only relevant as the path of files.
But that means there are no empty directories. If you list all files, all directories will be shown.
You can cut off the filename part to get all directories.

Something like

```
git ls-files ... | sed 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort -u
```

lists all directories that contain files listed acording to the specific options (`...`).
(This does not work with whitespace in file names - you will notice lines with space are quoted, and the quotes at start of lines mess up the `-u` (`--unique`).)

(If you want to work on **all** directories (which I noticed later) in your working copy, without any relation to the file subsets listed by various options of `git ls-files`, you may not need that at all, and an answer using `find` is more clear.)